# htaccess - add string to end url

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

The url is like

`http://www.example.com/?p=3733&preview=true`

and I want to add `?ModPagespeed=noscript`

so it becomes `http://www.example.com/?p=3733&preview=true?ModPagespeed=off`

p= is dynamic btw

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=[^&]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)preview=true(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)ModPagespeed=off(&|$)
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}?ModPagespeed=off [L,QSA,R]
```

**UPDATE:** If you want final URL with 2 `?` in it, use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=[^&]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)preview=true(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)ModPagespeed=off(&|$)
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}?ModPagespeed=off [L,NE,R]
```

Comment: Almost. The url ended up as:
http://www.example.com/?ModPagespeed=off&p=3736&preview=true

Comment: Is that not correct URL? What you gave in your example was wrong URI because it has `?` appearing twice.

Comment: The url is really correct with both ? in it. Already tried it. It's from Google PageSpeed.

Comment: So you want 2 `?` in the final URL?

Comment: Hmm reconfirmed because: `The question mark is used as a separator and is not part of the query string`. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: Still not yet, but I made a little mistake. The url should be
http://www.example.com/?p=3733&preview=true?ModPagespeed=noscript. With the current example it is not working

Comment: It still ends up like this and not at the end:
http://www.example.com/?ModPagespeed=noscript?p=3740&preview=true

Comment: ok rolled back my change in UPDATE section. In my testing final URI becomes `/?p=3733&preview=true?ModPagespeed=off` **exactly same** as your question.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm going to test it later. have to go. Thanks for all the time you put in it.