# automatically adding GET value to default url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Lets say that my domain is www.domain.com. I want to add GET variable to the every url which starts with domain.com. For example if user enters domain.com in browser, default get variable will be added so url will look like: domain.com?variable=default or if user enters domain.com/contact.php it will look like domain.com/contact.php?variable=default.

Thanks

Comment: can you use php? for example a header.php file? or need a htaccess rewrite?

Comment: I can use php. I could add header php file which will check if GET variable exists. If not, it will create one. Am I right?

Comment: also check this for htaccess approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/20650167/2543240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a say `header.php` file in all pages:

```
if ( !isset($_GET['variable']) ) {
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?variable=default');
}
```

Comment: I think that you gonna have indefinite loop in that case. Am I right?

Comment: a little mistake if ($_GET['variable']!= 'default') should be. Thank you!! :)

Comment: but if you are using isset, if user set different value, it will not be redirected to default value of GET variable

Comment: if you don't want it to be editable, then what's the point of being there?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use it like this?

```
if (isset($_GET['var'])) { 
    $var = $_GET['var'];
} else {
    $var = "default";
}
```

So if the var exist in URL, use that one. Else, use the default variable.

Or you could use a session to retrieve a variable that cannot be changed by the user.

```
// On first page
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); } 

$_SESSION['var'] = "var";

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

// On second page
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }

if (isset($_SESSION['var'])) { 
    $var = $_SESSION['var'];
} else {
    $var = "default";
}
```